# OAuth Dialog rendering problems in iPad

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, obsolete, oauth2

I'm using the implicit OAuth flow for our native iPad app. We're calling the standard URLs in a UIWebView. The Stack Exchange login renders with several UI glitches.

<del>The first screen looks correct:</del>
(Unrecoverable image deleted (not in any archive))

However, when you click on the Stack Exchange login the following is rendered:

[image: Step 2]

I've confirmed just opening the dialog URL on mobile Safari for iPad it also renders this way.

Comment: This actually looks like a bug in the Stack Exchange OpenId provider, I'm working on it but it will take a little longer than a plain-jane API bug.  Expect a fix sometime tomorrow.

Comment: I've deployed a potential fix, can you give it a go?  Works on our iPad 2 naturally, but iPads are... finicky in our experience.

Comment: i hit a similar roadblock building the client workflow for soapi2. i will try to spend some time with it today to verify.

Comment: It's better now. Thanks. I did find that if we turn off `[UIWebView scalesPageToFit]` it does still wrap. In case anyone else runs in to that.